# The variables are not recognized

Tags: powerapps

Set(VarAttachmentControl,JSON(Image1.Image,IncludeBinaryData));
Set(VarBase64,Mid(VarAttachmentControl, Find(",", VarAttachmentControl)+1, Len(VarAttachmentControl)-Find(",", VarAttachmentControl)-1));

I run into a problem in power apps. The variables are not recognized. However, when I use a ";" instead of "," in the first line, that goes well.

But then I can't use the second 'Set". It will not be recognized. Is there a weay to fix this?

Set(VarAttachmentControl;JSON(Image1.Image;IncludeBinaryData))

But then I can't use the second 'Set". It will not be recognized. Is there a weay to fix this?

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of the code

Comment: I have pasted your code into a Button.OnSelect. The JSON option was signalled as error, so I prefixed it (JSONformat.IncludeBinaryData). After that the code worked when I clicked the button. Not sure what you mean by 'not recognized'. Perhaps you were evaluating the variable before the code was ever executed?

Answer (score 1):

From https://learn.microsoft.com/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/global-apps#formula-separators-and-chaining-operator, if the decimal separator in your locale is `,`, then the "list separator" (the token used to separate parameters to a function) becomes `;`, and the "chaining operator" (what is used to separate two function calls in the same expression becomes `;;`. Since you say that using `;` as a list separator works in your scenario, your expression should be written as follows:

```
Set(
  VarAttachmentControl;
  JSON(Image1.Image; JSONFormat.IncludeBinaryData));;
Set(
  VarBase64;
  Mid(
    VarAttachmentControl;
    Find(","; VarAttachmentControl) + 1;
    Len(VarAttachmentControl) - Find(","; VarAttachmentControl) - 1
  )
);;
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing! This is  very helpful as a beginner using power apps.

Comment: and I added the code as below, the result is an error, please help correct it, thank you
 
TombolPowerApps.Run(
    Last(AttachmentControl.Attachments).Name;
    VarBase64
);;